# Dates verification to check of the given dates are within the range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query for checking 2 dates or more simultaneously to check if one of them is out of given range.

```
SELECT 
    sysdate 
FROM dual 
GROUP BY sysdate 
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN (SELECT sysdate, (sysdate+1) FROM dual) BETWEEN 
SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE+10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) > 0
```

I'm getting an exception

> ORA-00913: too many values

when tried with 2 dates.
Please advise

Comment: Your query does not contain two dates.  I would suggest that you show your actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why you would like such a query. But as the error says, `when` accepts one condition and so you would have to separate the query using `and`. Also `else null` part is not needed as it is the default.

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual 
GROUP BY sysdate 
HAVING COUNT(
           CASE WHEN (select sysdate from dual) BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE+10 
           AND (select sysdate+1 from dual) BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE+10 
           THEN 1 END
             ) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what vkp suggested that case when () expects one value to compare with another, but sysdate,sysdate + 1 returns 2 values which can't be compared together. So it is better to separate both conditions, but I would have done it in where clause like below

```
        SELECT 
            sysdate 
        FROM dual 
        GROUP BY sysdate 
        HAVING ( select count(*) from dual 
        WHERE 
            (SELECT sysdate FROM dual) BETWEEN 
            SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE+10 
        AND
            (SELECT sysdate+1 FROM dual) BETWEEN 
            SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE+10 ) > 0
```